# Jquery script doesn't load after HTML so page is a mess

Tags: html, jquery, reactjs

I have a Typescript React app. I have 3 files for one page:

timeline.tsx

```
import React from "react"
import './timeline.css'
import './script.js'

export default function Timeline() {
  return (
  <>
  
  <section className="cd-horizontal-timeline" >

  <meta httpEquiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta httpEquiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta httpEquiv="Expires" content="1" />

      <div className="timeline">
        
        <div className="events-wrapper">
          <div className="events">
            <ol>
              <li><a href="#0" data-date="16/01/2014" className="selected">Aug 2004</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/2014">20 Feb</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0" data-date="20/04/2014">20 Mar</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0" data-date="20/05/2014">20 May</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0" data-date="09/07/2014">09 Jul</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0" data-date="30/08/2014">30 Aug   </a></li>
              <li><a href="#0" data-date="15/09/2014">15 Sep </a></li>
              <li><a href="#0" data-date="01/11/2014">01 Nov</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0" data-date="10/12/2014">10 Dec</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0" data-date="19/01/2015">29 Jan</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0" data-date="03/03/2015">3 Mar</a></li>
            </ol>

            <span className="filling-line" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </div> 
        </div> 

        <ul className="cd-timeline-navigation">
          <li><a href="#0" className="prev inactive">Prev</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0" className="next">Next</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </div> 

      <div className="events-content">
        <ol>
          <li className="selected" data-date="16/01/2014">
            <h2>Horizontal Timeline</h2>
            <em>January 16th, 2014</em>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
            </p>
          </li>

          <li data-date="28/02/2014">
            <h2>Event title here</h2>
            <em>February 28th, 2014</em>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
            </p>
          </li>

          <li data-date="20/04/2014">
            <h2>Event title here</h2>
            <em>March 20th, 2014</em>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
            </p>
          </li>

          <li data-date="20/05/2014">
            <h2>Event title here</h2>
            <em>May 20th, 2014</em>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
            </p>
          </li>

          <li data-date="09/07/2014">
            <h2>Event title here</h2>
            <em>July 9th, 2014</em>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
            </p>
          </li>

          <li data-date="30/08/2014">
            <h2>Event title here</h2>
            <em>August 30th, 2014</em>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
            </p>
          </li>

          <li data-date="15/09/2014">
            <h2>Event title here</h2>
            <em>September 15th, 2014</em>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
            </p>
          </li>

          <li data-date="01/11/2014">
            <h2>Event title here</h2>
            <em>November 1st, 2014</em>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
            </p>
          </li>

          <li data-date="10/12/2014">
            <h2>Event title here</h2>
            <em>December 10th, 2014</em>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
            </p>
          </li>

          <li data-date="19/01/2015">
            <h2>Event title here</h2>
            <em>January 19th, 2015</em>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
            </p>
          </li>

          <li data-date="03/03/2015">
            <h2>Event title here</h2>
            <em>March 3rd, 2015</em>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
            </p>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div> 
    </section>

    <script src='script.js' ></script>

    </>
  )
}
```

script.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'

$(function($) {
    let i

    var timelines = $('.cd-horizontal-timeline'),
        eventsMinDistance = 60;

    (timelines.length > 0) && initTimeline(timelines);

    function initTimeline(timelines) {
        timelines.each(function() {
            var timeline = $(this),
                timelineComponents = {};
            //cache timeline components 
            timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'] = timeline.find('.events-wrapper');
            timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'] = timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].children('.events');
            timelineComponents['fillingLine'] = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].children('.filling-line');
            timelineComponents['timelineEvents'] = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('a');
            timelineComponents['timelineDates'] = parseDate(timelineComponents['timelineEvents']);
            timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse'] = minLapse(timelineComponents['timelineDates']);
            timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'] = timeline.find('.cd-timeline-navigation');
            timelineComponents['eventsContent'] = timeline.children('.events-content');

            //assign a left postion to the single events along the timeline
            setDatePosition(timelineComponents, eventsMinDistance);
            //assign a width to the timeline
            var timelineTotWidth = setTimelineWidth(timelineComponents, eventsMinDistance);
            //the timeline has been initialize - show it
            timeline.addClass('loaded');

            //detect click on the next arrow
            timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.next', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'next');
            });
            //detect click on the prev arrow
            timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.prev', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');
            });
            //detect click on the a single event - show new event content
            timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].on('click', 'a', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                updateOlderEvents($(this));
                updateFilling($(this), timelineComponents['fillingLine'], timelineTotWidth);
                updateVisibleContent($(this), timelineComponents['eventsContent']);
            });

            //on swipe, show next/prev event content
            timelineComponents['eventsContent'].on('swipeleft', function(){
                var mq = checkMQ();
                ( mq == 'mobile' ) && showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'next');
            });
            timelineComponents['eventsContent'].on('swiperight', function(){
                var mq = checkMQ();
                ( mq == 'mobile' ) && showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');
            });

            //keyboard navigation
            $(document).keyup(function(event){
                if(event.which=='37' && elementInViewport(timeline.get(0)) ) {
                    showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');
                } else if( event.which=='39' && elementInViewport(timeline.get(0))) {
                    showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'next');
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, string) {
        //retrieve translateX value of timelineComponents['eventsWrapper']
        var translateValue = getTranslateValue(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper']),
            wrapperWidth = Number(timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].css('width').replace('px', ''));
        //translate the timeline to the left('next')/right('prev') 
        (string == 'next') 
            ? translateTimeline(timelineComponents, translateValue - wrapperWidth + eventsMinDistance, wrapperWidth - timelineTotWidth)
            : translateTimeline(timelineComponents, translateValue + wrapperWidth - eventsMinDistance);
    }

    function showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, string) {
        //go from one event to the next/previous one
        var visibleContent =  timelineComponents['eventsContent'].find('.selected'),
            newContent = ( string == 'next' ) ? visibleContent.next() : visibleContent.prev();

        if ( newContent.length > 0 ) { //if there's a next/prev event - show it
            var selectedDate = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('.selected'),
                newEvent = ( string == 'next' ) ? selectedDate.parent('li').next('li').children('a') : selectedDate.parent('li').prev('li').children('a');
            
            updateFilling(newEvent, timelineComponents['fillingLine'], timelineTotWidth);
            updateVisibleContent(newEvent, timelineComponents['eventsContent']);
            newEvent.addClass('selected');
            selectedDate.removeClass('selected');
            updateOlderEvents(newEvent);
            updateTimelinePosition(string, newEvent, timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth);
        }
    }

    function updateTimelinePosition(string, event, timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth) {
        //translate timeline to the left/right according to the position of the selected event
        var eventStyle = window.getComputedStyle(event.get(0), null),
            eventLeft = Number(eventStyle.getPropertyValue("left").replace('px', '')),
            timelineWidth = Number(timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].css('width').replace('px', '')),
            timelineTotWidth = Number(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].css('width').replace('px', ''));
        var timelineTranslate = getTranslateValue(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper']);

        if( (string == 'next' && eventLeft > timelineWidth - timelineTranslate) || (string == 'prev' && eventLeft < - timelineTranslate) ) {
            translateTimeline(timelineComponents, - eventLeft + timelineWidth/2, timelineWidth - timelineTotWidth);
        }
    }

    function translateTimeline(timelineComponents, value, totWidth) {
        var eventsWrapper = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].get(0);
        value = (value > 0) ? 0 : value; //only negative translate value
        value = ( !(typeof totWidth === 'undefined') &&  value < totWidth ) ? totWidth : value; //do not translate more than timeline width
        setTransformValue(eventsWrapper, 'translateX', value+'px');
        //update navigation arrows visibility
        (value == 0 ) ? timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.prev').addClass('inactive') : timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.prev').removeClass('inactive');
        (value == totWidth ) ? timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.next').addClass('inactive') : timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].find('.next').removeClass('inactive');
    }

    function updateFilling(selectedEvent, filling, totWidth) {
        //change .filling-line length according to the selected event
        var eventStyle = window.getComputedStyle(selectedEvent.get(0), null),
            eventLeft = eventStyle.getPropertyValue("left"),
            eventWidth = eventStyle.getPropertyValue("width");
        eventLeft = Number(eventLeft.replace('px', '')) + Number(eventWidth.replace('px', ''))/2;
        var scaleValue = eventLeft/totWidth;
        setTransformValue(filling.get(0), 'scaleX', scaleValue);
    }

    function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
        for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) { 
            var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
                distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
            timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', distanceNorm*min+'px');
        }
    }

    function setTimelineWidth(timelineComponents, width) {
        var timeSpan = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length-1]),
            timeSpanNorm = timeSpan/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse'],
            timeSpanNorm = Math.round(timeSpanNorm) + 4,
            totalWidth = timeSpanNorm*width;
        timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].css('width', totalWidth+'px');
        updateFilling(timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(0), timelineComponents['fillingLine'], totalWidth);
    
        return totalWidth;
    }

    function updateVisibleContent(event, eventsContent) {
        var eventDate = event.data('date'),
            visibleContent = eventsContent.find('.selected'),
            selectedContent = eventsContent.find('[data-date="'+ eventDate +'"]'),
            selectedContentHeight = selectedContent.height();

        if (selectedContent.index() > visibleContent.index()) {
            var classEnetering = 'selected enter-right',
                classLeaving = 'leave-left';
        } else {
            var classEnetering = 'selected enter-left',
                classLeaving = 'leave-right';
        }

        selectedContent.attr('class', classEnetering);
        visibleContent.attr('class', classLeaving).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(){
            visibleContent.removeClass('leave-right leave-left');
            selectedContent.removeClass('enter-left enter-right');
        });
        eventsContent.css('height', selectedContentHeight+'px');
    }

    function updateOlderEvents(event) {
        event.parent('li').prevAll('li').children('a').addClass('older-event').end().end().nextAll('li').children('a').removeClass('older-event');
    }

    function getTranslateValue(timeline) {
        var timelineStyle = window.getComputedStyle(timeline.get(0), null),
            timelineTranslate = timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
                timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
                timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
                timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
                timelineStyle.getPropertyValue("transform");

        if( timelineTranslate.indexOf('(') >=0 ) {
            var timelineTranslate = timelineTranslate.split('(')[1];
            timelineTranslate = timelineTranslate.split(')')[0];
            timelineTranslate = timelineTranslate.split(',');
            var translateValue = timelineTranslate[4];
        } else {
            var translateValue = 0;
        }

        return Number(translateValue);
    }

    function setTransformValue(element, property, value) {
        element.style["-webkit-transform"] = property+"("+value+")";
        element.style["-moz-transform"] = property+"("+value+")";
        element.style["-ms-transform"] = property+"("+value+")";
        element.style["-o-transform"] = property+"("+value+")";
        element.style["transform"] = property+"("+value+")";
    }

    
    function parseDate(events) {
        var dateArrays = [];
        events.each(function(){
            var dateComp = $(this).data('date').split('/'),
                newDate = new Date(dateComp[2], dateComp[1]-1, dateComp[0]);
            dateArrays.push(newDate);
        });
        return dateArrays;
    }

    function parseDate2(events) {
        var dateArrays = [];
        events.each(function(){
            var singleDate = $(this),
                dateComp = singleDate.data('date').split('T');
            if( dateComp.length > 1 ) { //both DD/MM/YEAR and time are provided
                var dayComp = dateComp[0].split('/'),
                    timeComp = dateComp[1].split(':');
            } else if( dateComp[0].indexOf(':') >=0 ) { //only time is provide
                var dayComp = ["2000", "0", "0"],
                    timeComp = dateComp[0].split(':');
            } else { //only DD/MM/YEAR
                var dayComp = dateComp[0].split('/'),
                    timeComp = ["0", "0"];
            }
            var newDate = new Date(dayComp[2], dayComp[1]-1, dayComp[0], timeComp[0], timeComp[1]);
            dateArrays.push(newDate);
        });
        return dateArrays;
    }

    function daydiff(first, second) {
        return Math.round((second-first));
    }

    function minLapse(dates) {
    
        var dateDistances = [];
        for (i = 1; i < dates.length; i++) { 
            var distance = daydiff(dates[i-1], dates[i]);
            dateDistances.push(distance);
        }
        return Math.min.apply(null, dateDistances);
    }


    function elementInViewport(el) {
        var top = el.offsetTop;
        var left = el.offsetLeft;
        var width = el.offsetWidth;
        var height = el.offsetHeight;

        while(el.offsetParent) {
            el = el.offsetParent;
            top += el.offsetTop;
            left += el.offsetLeft;
        }

        return (
            top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
            left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth) &&
            (top + height) > window.pageYOffset &&
            (left + width) > window.pageXOffset
        );
    }

    function checkMQ() {
        
        return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.cd-horizontal-timeline'), '::before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/'/g, "").replace(/"/g, "");
    }

    
});
```

and a .css file. I dont know why but when my page loads the JS dosent and all the elements are a mess all loading the the same spot. Only when I refresh the page does the JS load and the page correctly.

I searched the internet but all I could find were functions that are no longer supported by the current version of jq. I am unsure what is wrong. I have also tried adding defer to my script tag but I still have the same issue.